# Is the promise returned by new Promise() resolved or rejected synchronously as soon as the executor is executed?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, synchronous

It is said that the callback (called executor) that executes the constructor `new Promise()` is always executed [synchronously](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/Promise#description), therefore, the following question arises:

> 3. The executor is called **synchronously** (as soon as the Promise is constructed) with the `resolveFunc` and `rejectFunc` functions as
>    arguments.

Is the promise returned by `new Promise()` **also** resolved or rejected synchronously as soon as the executor is executed?

```
const myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  if (/* some condition */) {
    resolve('Promise fulfilled');
  } else {
    reject('Promise rejected');
  }
});

// The promise has been created and its fate (resolved or rejected) is now determined.
// But we can only see its status when JavaScript has completed the execution of the current code and has emptied the callstack
```

I don't want to do something concrete, **I just want to evaluate my knowledge**.

Comment: No, not always. It depends on what the executor callback does. Sure, if it immediately resolves the promise, then the promise is immediately resolved.

Comment: "*we can only see its status when JavaScript has completed the execution of the current code and has emptied the callstack*" - that's not actually true, with a debugger you inspect the promise at any point in time and see that is has been fulfilled with a value.

Comment: But even if the promise is resolved immediately, you can only access its value after you `await` it or in the `.then()` handler ...

Comment: To rephrase the point: Promise constructor callbacks are synchronously executed and `resolve` is a function call (also executed synchronously). So it's entirely possible that the Promise resolves synchronously with no delay. It doesn't really matter practically though because you can't "unwrap" the value without queueing a microtask, so even if it resolves synchronously you can only *access the inner value* asynchronously.

Comment: "*Sure, if it immediately resolves the promise, then the promise is immediately resolved*" - That would happen if the code inside the executor has **pure** synchronous code, right? @Bergi

Comment: @jwa Yes, like in your example snippet. But due to the tautology, I'm not quite sure how to answer this question.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got the idea,. "*No, not always. It depends on what the executor callback does*" - For example, if in the executor there was a `setTimeout()` and there in the `setTimeout()` `reject()`/`resolve()` was called, right? @Bergi

Comment: Hi @derpirscher, right, that's right, that's why I put the last comment in the code

Comment: Yes, if it's called later, then it's asynchronous by definition.

Comment: "*that's not actually true, with a debugger you inspect the promise at any point in time and see that is has been fulfilled with a value.*" -  **But assuming we're not talking about debugging**, it runs all the synchronous code from the single JavaScript thread first and then the asynchronous code, hence the state of the promise is "known" when it's time for the asynchronous code, right? @Bergi

Comment: Hi @Jared Smith, thanks. So, my 2 comments in my code are correct, right?

Comment: @jwa yes except for the bit about the "callstack". You're not in a function call so there is no call stack. Promises enqueue microtasks resolved during [microtask resolution](https://javascript.info/event-loop) as part of the JS event loop.

Comment: "*You're not in a function call so there is no call stack*" - I mention callstack because in a more "real" application there is synchronous code, asynchronous code, function calls, etc @Jared Smith

Comment: @jwa the state of the promise is known as soon as the `resolve()` call has completed. And this fulfillment of the promise is what causes the registered promise callbacks to be scheduled for asynchronous execution in the first place.

Comment: Excellent. Asynchronous code, such as `then()`/`catch()`/`finally()` callbacks are executed when the single JavaScript thread is free, i.e. when it has finished executing all synchronous code (i.e. when the call stack is empty), right? @Bergi

Comment: Yes, that's how the event loop works.